# Can document change on a window?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

In JavaScript on the web, are there any circumstances when a `document` property of a global `window` would change its value to a new document?

I don't mind if it's an unusual corner case that doesn't happen in real life.
I'd like to know if I can assume that, given a `window`, the `document` will 100% be the same all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Using `document.write` after page load can do weird edge-case things.  I don't know if it creates a new value of `document` or not but the script can keep running while the DOM is cleared.

**EDIT**

Just tested this with Chrome and `document` didn't change.  NOt easy to test the other browsers ATM.

```
function z() {
  var k = document;
  document.write("Test");
  var k1 = document;
  alert(k === k1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a window object for each document.

The global window object is a WindowProxy object. When the [browsing context is navigated](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/browsers.html#navigate), the document object changes, and the global window object represents the window associated with the new document.

Moreover, the window object of the document itself can also change:

From the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/browsers.html#windows):

> Note: In general, there is a 1-to-1 mapping from the Window object to
>   the Document object. There are two exceptions. First, a Window can be
>   reused for the presentation of a second Document in the same browsing
>   context, such that the mapping is then 1-to-2. This occurs when a
>   browsing context is navigated from the initial about:blank Document to
>   another, with replacement enabled. Second, a Document can end up being
>   reused for several Window objects when the document.open() method is
>   used, such that the mapping is then many-to-1.

So, in short, the document object on the global window object *can* change.